# CakePHP use wrong sequence name (PostgreSQL)

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, sequence, postgresql-9.1

When I try save some information in Postgres table, CakePHP return this error for me:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => '[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERRO:  relaÃ§Ã£o "public.cashier_transaction_transaction_num_seq" nÃ£o existe
Request URL: /www/cashiers/open
Stack Trace:
```

But CakePHP is correctly: this sequence doesn't exist. The correct sequence is **transaction_num_seq**.

How can I change that **IN CAKE** (I can't change the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to fix this error, was creating an action in each model named "nextval ()" for example, and run the default PostgreSQL query to get the next sequence.

```
public function nextval() {
    $sql = "select nextval('transaction_num_seq') as nextval";
    $result = $this->query($sql);
    return $result[0][0]['nextval'];
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this maybe it could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12806856/1695418

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an undocumented, optional attribute used by the **describe($model)** function in **Postgres.php**

```
if (isset($model->sequence)) {
    $this->_sequenceMap[$table][$model->primaryKey] = $model->sequence;
}
```

Use it, like so, to specify the sequence of the table's primary key.

```
public class YourModel extends AppModel {
    public $sequence = 'public.foobar_seq';
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Actually I had not noticed it. Thank you my friend.