# How to make my Model class use postgresql sequence in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp-2.0

Following the [Cakephp (2.x) Blog Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html), I created the table **posts** in **Postgresql 9.x**:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    body TEXT,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE posts_id_seq owned BY posts.id;
```

When trying to add a Post I got a **SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation** complaining that the id was null in the following:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("created", "title", "body", "modified") VALUES ('now()', 'x', 'x', '2014-01-10 10:58:49')
```

That happened because the sequence was not being called during create operations. After a little googleing I found suggestions that I had to [specify the sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965410/cakephp-use-wrong-sequence-name-postgresql) name or create a nextval method in my model class (Post). Unfortunately, both suggestions failed to solve the problem. Here is my model class:

```
class Post extends AppModel {

    public $sequence = 'posts_id_seq';
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );

    public function nextval() {
        $sql = "select nextval('posts_id_seq') as nextval";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        return $result[0][0]['nextval'];
    }

}
```

And this is the controller method being called:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Post->create();
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
}
```

Is there any way to tell CakePHP to use the posts_id_seq sequence?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems the easiest solution would be defining the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    body TEXT,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
    modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
);
```

`SERIAL` is the pg way of doing an autoincrementing integer.